# How do I save in Dungeon Siege 3?

Tags: dungeon-siege-3

OK, I feel like this should be a question that I don't need to ask, but I couldn't find an explanation anywhere.

I am playing the full version of Dungeon Siege 3 (not the demo, which doesn't allow saving).  I walked up to a save point beacon, and the game popped up a little "hint" explaining that this was a save point.  But it didn't tell me what to do with it, nor did it appear that it had auto-saved when I touched it.  I tried bringing up the game menu, but there was no Save Game option, only Load Game (and that only showed my last auto-save).

So how do I actually save at a save point?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press the 'use' button/key while standing in the save point to activate the save menu.

The defaults for *use* are are <kbd>E</kbd> on the PC and <kbd>R1</kbd> on the PlayStation 3.

Comment: I knew it had to be something obvious.  I blame bad UI consistency, since I didn't get the usual "floating hand" that indicates I should press the E key.